How do I connect Delphi to a website using MS Access database?
I want to create a local website for a registration form where the user can register and then login using the Delphi language. I need the info from the website to be saved in a database and the application needs to be able to access that information.
I tried to do it with HTML, but I figured out you can't connect it to a MS Access database.

"and then login using the delphi application" - what's the point of your program then? It could also handle registrations and logins - why the reroute of wanting to use HTML (and possibly HTTP)?

An HTML webpage can't connect to a database directly, so your HTML webform will have to submit the data to an HTTP server, which can then connect to and update the database on the webpage's behalf.
If you want everything to be local, you can build an HTTP server into your application, such as with Indy's TIdHTTPServer component, or DataSnap, or any other similar web technology.

As a general rule, to build a working web site, then you need a running instance of that web server. That web server can be say Apache, or IIS (Internet Information Services).
Hence, you have to be running a web site on a computer or server of your choosing. That web site can then directly use and update the Access database, and so thus can your Delphi program also open and use that Access database. However, since server-based database systems have free versions of such databases? Then in most cases, it is recommended to use say SQL server.
If the Access database has more then just tables, such as forms and reports?
Then the recommended road is to migrate the Access data to the database server. You then use linked tables from Access.
The result is thus:
Access forms, reports, VBA code etc. can continue to be used, but now the data resides in SQL server, and you use linked tables from Access.
The web server can also now use SQL Server, and use the same database.
Your Delphi code and software can also now use SQL Server, and once again, then all software systems are sharing one common database.
While for a few users, Access databases can be used for the web server, but this is not a recommended setup.
So, it somewhat depends on how many users and the workload the web server going to have. For a quick setup, and starting out, then you can have the web site pages use and consume data from that Access database, but it not going to scale all that great. So, future plans should be to migrate the data from Access to some kind of server database system such as SQL Server.
Of course, if the web server not part of your internal network, then the Access database file (accDB) will be placed on the server running the Web Server software, and thus it becomes rather difficult to have software on your local company network such as vb.net, or Delphi reach and open the Access database.
So, you need a web server, and that web server can then dish out web pages, and that web server code you write (in C#, or VB.net) for the web site can open and consume the Access database. So, regardless of what database system you choose, you still need to dedicate a computer to run a web server for this to work.
